# Multiply Varying number of Values Inside array: Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

I have arranged my data so that the documents belonging to the same customer id are aggregated into a single collection. The data format is as follows.

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "stock_code": [
            "22617",
            "22768",
            "20749"
        ],
        "description": [
            "DESIGN",
            "FAMILY PHOTO FRAME",
            "ASSORTED CASES"
        ],
        "quantity": [
            18,
            12,
            84
        ],
        "unit_price": [
            4.95,
            9.95,
            6.35
        ]
    }
],
"_id": 581485,
"customer_id": 17389,
"country": "United Kingdom"
}
```

I need to multiply the values of array quantity with corresponding unit_price and get a total for multiple documents in a new field. I have tried using the $reduce function and $map function to get the output but both of them result in "error"

> Multiply only supports numeric types, and not arrays

Could you please suggest how should i go about accomplishing this.

Codes tried:

```
"$addFields": {"order_total" : 
                 { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$items", 
                    "as": "items", 
                    "in": { "$multiply": [ 
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$$items.quantity", 0 ] }, 
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$$items.unit_price", 0 ] } 
                     ]} 
                    }
                } 
              }
            }
```

Second:

```
"order_total" : {
            "$reduce" : {
                "input" : "$items",
                "initialValue" : Decimal128("0.00"),
                "in": {
                    "$sum" : [
                        "$$value",
                        {"$multiply" : [ "$$this.quantity", "$$this.unit_price" ] }
                    ]}
             }
       }
```

The expected result needs to add a new field of "total" by multiplying the corresponding entries of unit_price with quantity. The error message is that of **multiply only supports numeric types and not arrays**.

Answer (score 0):

I would decompose the problem into solvable chunks beginning with the smallest unit and start with the two arrays `quantity` and `unit_price`.

So given just a document with the structure

```
{
    "quantity": [ 18, 12, 84 ],
    "unit_price": [ 4.95, 9.95, 6.35 ]
}
```

We can add another field with the totals for each element in both arrays i.e.

```
{
    "quantity": [ 18, 12, 84 ],
    "unit_price": [ 4.95, 9.95, 6.35 ],
    "total": [ 89.1, 119.4, 533.4 ]
}
```

This field can be computed using [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) within [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as

```
{ 
    "total": {
        "$map": {
            "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$quantity" } ] },
            "as": "idx",
            "in": {
                "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                        "qty": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$quantity", "$$idx" ] },
                        "price": { 
                            "$ifNull": [
                                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$unit_price", "$$idx" ] },
                                0
                            ] 
                        }
                    },
                    "in": { "$multiply": [ "$$qty", "$$price" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This then becomes basis for calculating the `order_total` field with two pipeline stages for clarity (although can be composed into a single pipeline with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) for brevity)

```
var totalMapExpression = {
    "$map": {
        "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$$item.quantity" } ] },
        "as": "idx",
        "in": {
            "$let": {
                "vars": {
                    "qty": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$item.quantity", "$$idx" ] },
                    "price": { 
                        "$ifNull": [
                            { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$item.unit_price", "$$idx" ] },
                            0
                        ] 
                    }
                },
                "in": { "$multiply": [ "$$qty", "$$price" ] }
            }
        }
    }
};

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "items": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$items",
                "as": "item",
                "in": {
                    "quantity": "$$item.quantity",
                    "unit_price": "$$item.unit_price",
                    "stock_code": "$$item.stock_code",
                    "description": "$$item.description",
                    "total": { "$sum": totalMapExpression }
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "order_total": {  "$sum": "$items.total" }
    } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[{ $unwind: { path: "$items",} }, 
{ $unwind: {  path: "$items.quantity",} }, 
{ $unwind: {  path: "$items.unit_price",} }, 
{ $addFields: { 'total': {$multiply:   ["$items.quantity", "$items.unit_price"]  }} }])
```